# What is the alternative to dict as way to parameterize python class?

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I usually see the following python code around the codebase I work with:

```
class A:
    def do_something(self):
        pass

class B:
    def do_something(self):
        pass


class C:
    _magic_dict = {'option1' : A, 'option2' : B}

   def do_something_else(self, option):
       # call some other methods, functiosn
       my_option = _magic_dict['option']()
       my_option.do_something()

       self.do_more_things(my_option)
```

So the basic idea is to make class C generic to A or B. 
Is this a common practice? I feel like it is an overuse of dicts and the fact that everything (in this case the class) is an object that can be passed around.

For a more specific problem, the following example might help. There is a class responsible to take a given metric object, which in the end is a dict of objects holding the info for that type of metric. And there is a statistics reporter which will take a given metric object, choose a type of data it is interested to report (one of the entries in the dict, let's say) and output that in a pretty format. So:

```
class FoodMetric:
    def __init__(self, path_to_my_stock_files):
        self._path = path_to_my_stock_files
        self._data = {}

    def parse(self):
        # let's assume that after parsing the files, the following data would have been obtained:
        # self.data = {'cheese' : {'cheddar' : 10, 'goat' : 20}}

class WoodFastenerMetric:
    def __init__(self, path_to_my_stock_files):
        self._path = path_to_my_stock_files
        self._data = {}

    def parse(self):
        # let's assume that after parsing the files, the following data would have been obtained:
        # self.data = {'nails' : {'round' : 10, 'oval' : 20}}

class StatsReporter:

    _magic_dict = {'food' : (FoodMetric, ['column1', 'column2'], 'cheese')
                   'wood_fastener' : (WoodFastener, ['columnA', 'columnB'], 'nail')
                  }      

    def present_data(metric_type):
        the_class, columns, data_set_name = _magic_dict(metric_type)
        metric = the_class(self._path) # assume I have the path for the files here
        metric.parse()
        print(self._convert_to_table(metric, columns, data_set_name))
```

I do have an alternative implementation in mind which creates C by passing an instance of either of A or B to it, therefore eliminating this dictionary lookup inside C.

What are other alternatives, or is the solution stated in the question a common way to solve this in python?

P.S.: I hope the example make the intent more clear.

Comment: What is the actual problem which you are trying to solve with this approach? This is definitely not the best approach regardless of what you are doing, the best solution depends on the actual problem...

Comment: "I feel like it is an overuse of dicts" — I feel like it is an overuse of classes.

Comment: The code you've shared will not execute. The values in the magical dict are references to the classes and not to the instances and passing instances might not be what you want, maybe you want to instantiate an instance A or B depending on the option. It also sounds like you are refactoring something that might be working already, you might want to check with your team.

Answer (score 2):

Using the same class and method names as in the original question, and lacking any information about the actual problem being solved, I would refactor the code into the following:

```
class C:
   def do_something_else(self):
       self.do_something()
       self.do_more_things()

    def do_something(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class A(C):
    def do_something(self):
        pass

class B(C):
    def do_something(self):
        pass

def make_instance(option):
    return {'option1' : A, 'option2' : B}[option]()

instance = make_instance(option)
instance.do_something_else()
```

With that approach, the design is clear: `C` implements common functionality, whereas `A` and `B` are specializations of it.

The only *ugly* part remaining is the `make_instance` function, which can probably also be better, but not the way the question was stated, because it is not clear where `option` comes from.

Comment: `make_instance` may be a little ugly, but you demonstrated a more top-down inheritance scheme without changing too much else, which really is the root of the problem imo. That said, if it works - it works. More importantly if it's already very common within a code base it might be worth just sticking to that style for that project.